# how to read a property's value of value in Mule4?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

I have a property defined in properties file.Note client1 prefix, which is calculated dynamically when request hits.

```
client1_appilicationid=OBCDSEFT
```

i have 2 variables defined in my flow;

```
<set-variable value="#[attributes.headers.'x-client-id']" doc:name="ClientId" doc:id="1e33f179" variableName="clientid"/>
```

Here `attributes.headers.'x-client-id'` =`client1`

```
<set-variable value="'#[vars.clientid]'++'_'++'applicationid'" doc:name="applicationId" doc:id="9df0420e" variableName="applicationid"/>
```

In the above if i access `#[vars.applicationd]` it will print `client1_appilicationid` as value. but i want '`OBCDSEFT`' as value. How I can define `applicationId` variable to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just concatenating the client id header value with the suffix, however that will not read a property value. You should use the [p() function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-mule-functions-p) to read properties values.

The expression should be something like this: `#[p(vars.clientid++'_'++'applicationid')]`